# Logging numeric values as numbers using NLog Layout Renders

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

We could use [NLog Layout Renders](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers) to add custom fields in our logs. Here is my config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
    <targets async="true">
      <target
        name="clp"
        type="Console">
        <layout type="JsonLayout">
          <attribute name="duration" layout="${aspnet-item:variable=RequestDuration}" />
        </layout>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="clp" minlevel="Trace" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

The value of `aspnet-item:variable=RequestDuration` is calculated in my logging middleware:

```
public class RequestLoggingMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var startTime = this.clock.UtcNow;

        await this.next.Invoke(context);

        var endTime = this.clock.UtcNow;
        var requestDuration = (long)(endTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        context.Items["RequestDuration"] = requestDuration;
    }
}
```

Which is registered in my `Startup` like:

```
app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
```

And here is how I configure NLog:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStructureMap().UseStartup<Startup>().ConfigureAppConfiguration(AppConfig)
        .ConfigureLogging(
            (context, logging) =>
                {
                    LogManager.LoadConfiguration($"nlog.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.config");
                    logging.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions { CaptureMessageTemplates = true, CaptureMessageProperties = true });
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                }).UseNLog();
}
```

And if I log something like:

```
Logger.Info("this is just a test");
```

It will show up like this in the console output:

```
{ "duration": "123"}
```

I.e. although the value of `aspnet-item:variable=RequestDuration` is long, the duration will be rendered as a string. However, I would like it to be logged as a number. (We use ELK stack, and being able to log the custom values as numbers would allow us to add filters, for example, on the range of the values of such fields in Kibana)

**Application and package versions**

- .NET Core 3.1
- NLog 4.7.4
- NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.6.5
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little trick with JsonLayout Attribute, as once can specify `encode="false"`. It is usually used when using JsonLayout for the Attribute-Layout.

```
    <layout type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="duration" layout="${aspnet-item:variable=RequestDuration}" encode="false" />
    </layout>
```

If the item `RequestDuration` is guaranteed to be either an integer or empty, then it will generate the json-property without quotes. And it will be parsed as an integer, instead as a string.

NLog 5.0 will improve on this as Attribute will get a `ValueType`-property, so one can specify other than string-type (And also get validation of value-type). Instead of using the trick with `encode="False"`.

Answer (score 2):

For the plain file log, there are no types, so `My custom string` and `42` will be printed as just those values: `My custom string` and `42`  (don't get confused by the quotes in the documentation)

Some layouts support types, like the JSON layout.

For example:

```xml
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name='jsonFile' type='File' fileName='log.json'>
      <layout type='JsonLayout'>
        <attribute name='time' layout='${longdate}' />
        <attribute name='level' layout='${level:upperCase=true}'/>
        <attribute name='answer' layout='${event-properties:item=TheAnswer}'/>
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="jsonFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Will result in this JSON:

```json
{ "time": "2021-02-11 01:04:55.0000", "level": "INFO", "answer": 42 }
```

## Side note, the logger call

The logger call is now recommend to write like this:

```cs
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); // static field recommend

logger.Info("The real answer is {TheAnswer}", 42);
```

Or if you don't need 42 in the message (`${message}`) - NLog 4.6.3+

```cs
logger.WithProperty("TheAnswer", 42).Info("Hello There");
```

Comment: I added more details to my question, can you please take another look? @Julian